# What are these flowers on Kerguelen?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

What are these plants, which resemble short pink sunflowers, in this photograph from Kerguelen island? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[acaena magellanica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acaena_magellanica)* which is also called "Buzzy Burr" or "Greater Burnett". See these images for comparision (from [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/stationalpinejosephfourier/1396348285) and [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerguelen#Flora)):

[image]

[image]